# Regex to match lines starting with a \t or - but only capture - on

Tags: regex

I cannot figure out this regex for the life of me

I have example input such as:

`- Line 1
    - Line 2
        - Line 3
- Line 4`

I am trying to match each line starting at the - and going through the end of the line.  I am using the Workflow app on iOS which uses ICU regex parsing

The pattern I am using is

```
(?m)^\t*(-.*)
```

This pattern will match all the lines, but it captures the tabs.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just work around it with `(?m)(?<=^\t{0,100})-.*`. I doubt you can have more than 100 tabs there.

Comment: It works for me.  Why does my regex capture the tabs?

Comment: I tried to explain in my answer below.

Comment: From the doc's: `After finding a match, additional information is available about the range of the input matched, and the contents of any capture groups. ... group() Return a UnicodeString containing the text that was matched`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask why your regex *captures* the tabs. It is not so: your regex *matches* the tabs, and *captures* the `-` after those tabs with the rest of the line. The point is that you are using *consuming* pattern, the one that will return the matched/captured strings.

Non-consuming patterns - lookarounds - can be used to just check for some text presence/absence that do not actually put it into the text returned.

In [ICU regex flavor](http://www.icu-project.org/userguide/regexp), the lookbehinds are of *constrained-width*, that is, if you use a [*limiting quantifier*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit), it is OK to use it. (*The length of possible strings matched by the look-behind pattern must not be unbounded (no `*` or `+` operators.)*

Thus, **this will work in case there can be 100 and fewer tabs at the line start**:

```
(?m)(?<=^\t{0,100})-.*
```

Here,

- `(?m)` - makes `^` match the start of  a *line*
- `(?<=^\t{0,100})` - a positive lookbehind requiring 0 to 100 tabs after the beginning of the line to appear before a
- `-.*` - hyphen and the rest of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?m)^[ \t]*(-.*)
```

First, it appears that you have some spaces at the beginning of some of those lines, so `\t` will not match spaces. Replacing `\t` with `[ \t]` (or just `\s`) will fix this. Also, `(-*)` is going to match and capture any number of `-`, not including what's following. Put a `.` before your `*` to match any number of characters following the `-`, like this: `(-.*)`

If you don't require leading spaces, you can use

```
(?m)(-.*)
```

If you don't care about capturing the match, you don't need the parenthesis, giving you

```
(?m)-.*
```

As mentioned in the comments

Comment: The leading spaces are my inability to edit SO correctly. The 2nd suggestion doesn't work. I want the the line to start with - outside of tabs.

Comment: @lieutenantmudd: If you want to start a code formatting with space, use `<code> </code>`.